# Erro de instância

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, mvc, crud

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
```

A linha que ta gerando o erro é a seguinte:

```
var _TceView = MapperFacade.MapperConfiguration.Map<TceView>(await _TceRepositorio.buscarTce(pIdTce));
```

Qual o problema? Já fucei o código todo e não consigo encontrar.

Comment: A `Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto` ocorre quando você tenta fazer algo em um objeto `nulo`. Olhando o seu código acredito que o `_TceRepositorio.buscarTce(pIdTce)`nã0 está retornado um registro, e o `MapperFacade.MapperConfiguration.Map<TceView>`ao tentar fazer `TceView.Campo`dá o erro em questão.

Comment: ou o próprio `_TceRepositorio` não foi instanciado

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o retorno do método `_TceRepositorio.buscarTce(pIdTce)`. Ele deve estar retornando um valor nulo. Abaixo uma abordagem que facilite a sua verificação:

```
var testObject = await _TceRepositorio.buscarTce(pIdTce);

// Coloque um breakpoint neste ponto e verifique se o testObject está nulo, 
// isto deve estar causando o seu erro, caso esteja chegando um valor nulo, 
// implemente verificações no código para tratar situações como esta.
var _TceView = MapperFacade.MapperConfiguration.Map<TceView>(testObject);
```

Valide melhor sua regra de negócio para identificar se o objeto retornado pelo método `buscarTce()` pode ou não trabalhar com valores nulos.

Comment: Fiz isso porém está trazendo o objeto sim, continuo recebendo o mesmo erro quando chega na linha:                                                                                                         var _TceView = MapperFacade.MapperConfiguration.Map<TceView>(testObject);

Comment: @JoãoIgnácio, então o que pode estar acontecendo é alguma propriedade do objeto TceView que está vindo nulo e a classe não aceita nulo.

Comment: O que aconteceu foi que no start da aplicação não estava sendo instanciada a classe do automapper sendo assim o mapeamento não estava acontecendo, fiz a alteração e a aplicação rodou normalmente.